# Invalid characters or punctuation with Excel import

Tags: asp.net, excel-import

I'm retrieving data from Excel from my asp.net page
 The WorkSheet name is StatusPasPorts.

When I remove the column [Account Reference No.] it does work fine, but if I
use it I get

> `error : '' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.`
>
> `SELECT [Event Date],[Mobile Number],[Event Type Name],[Identification Method],[Customer DOB],[Account Reference No.] FROM [StatusPasPorts$] where Date] ASC`

Any ideas what is missing?

Comment: try with select * from  [StatusPasPorts$]

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the dot at the end of the column name - 'Account Reference No.'
Name it as 'Account Reference No'